# Can SELECT statements be injected?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I'm in the process of recoding ALL the sql statements on my site to use PDO and prepared statements. Ive tried my best to get a handle of how SQL injection works so i have a question.

If i have a page say viewitems.php the page will query the database and pull in all the data from a table and display it all on the page. Since the user doesnt have any input can this be injected? I'm aware pages using data drill down with header variables can be injected since the user can mess with the header but if the SQL is coded into the page with no need to any external variables can it be injected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm in the process of recoding ALL the sql statements on my site to use PDO and prepared statements.

**Bravo.**

> Since the user doesnt have any input can this be injected? If the SQL is coded into the page with no need to any external variables can it be injected?

If there are no run-time variables in the SQL statements, then no, the statement is not vulnerable to SQL injection. There is still no harm in using prepared statements in such cases. It might even be beneficial to do so for a number of reasons:

- Consistency with other code that does need to use prepared statements (for security)
- Future-proofing for if/when you do need parameters in the query
- Query caching (though this is dependent on your specific database and/or driver; see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1884576/139010) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2433350/139010))

Comment: ok so thats good to know cos there really is a lot of sql statements i just want to do the important ones for now so i can be safe but i will take your advice and go and make them all prepared when i have the chance

Answer (score 0):

> Can SELECT statements be injected?

YES
in general.

However, if the SQL is coded into the page with no variables, of course, no injection could be possible, as there is nothing to inject.

However, if the SQL is coded into the page with some variables injected, though "non-external", a second order injection is quite possible.
That's why **prepared statements can do any good if used always, with no exceptions.**